# Batch not-equal to all text strings

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

When using the batch and comparing two strings and comparing all available choices is done like this 
if /I %variable%==Something ( 
 echo wuhu
) 
But what i want to do is have a "if not" to all types of one specific string, this should be done like. 
if not /I %variable%==Something (
 echo Does not work 
)

But as far as i can see this does not work.
Is there any way to do it without using for loops in batch?

Answer (score 3):

The switch `/i` is related to the command `IF`, whereas `not` is a part of the expression.

The correct syntax is:

```
if /I not "%variable%"=="Something"
```

P.S. The quotes are added for reliability to handle a possibly empty variable.

Comment: thanks, were doing something wrong inside the if sentence to and missread the "great" error message to batch :)